# XElement - reading the nodes C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have an XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<productfeed>
    <product>
        <name>x</name>
        <etc>z</etc>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>x</name>
        <etc>z</etc>
    </product>
</productfeed>
```

I tried today LINQ and XElement to retrieve the data from the XML. I manage to load the file, however I cannot access `productfeed` node (it returns null). Interestingly I can iterate through `product` nodes straight from the root, while I read that one should not skip like that. Do I interpret something wrongly, perhaps `productfeed` node is already in the root, but then how would I get its pure contents?

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("...path..."); // works
XElement productFeed = root.Element("productfeed"); // returns null
IEnumerable<XElement> products = root.Elements("product"); // works
```

Comment: check the XElement.Document property.  I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `root` is `<productfeed>`.

Comment: What do you mean in getting "pure contents"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally you should load this into an XDocument. That would have had a `<productfeed>` element as a Root property.

XElement lets you skip this step, it can act as Document and root at the same time. The fix is very simple:

```
XElement productFeed = root; //.Element("productfeed");
```

`XElement` and `XDocument` do Parse the same content but XDocument has a (more complete) document wrapper, you will need that when dealing with the `<? >` Processing Instructions etc.

Comment: the answer as the previous comments is useful. However if I try: XElement root = XElement("..path.."); or XDocument rootDocument = XDocument("...path..."); the parsed result is exactly the same.What would be the difference then?

Comment: Ok, maybe they are parsed the same, but I see there is a difference. I can go step by step when using XDocument when loading. Thanks!